# How to set a background image to fit 100% of the div in a flex container with flex-direction: column and set the height dynamically?

Tags: html, css

I have a flex-container where some of the items are divs that have images as background:

```css
.column_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex_image {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("my_img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="column_flex_container">
  <div class="flex_item flex_image">

  </div>
</div>
```

Since the height is not set, it will be 0. But how can I make it set the height according to the width and resolution?

So that the image will fit the 100% width of the flex container and change the height dynamically without losing its aspect-ratio.

Is it possible?

Comment: To do that, the image will need to be referenced in your HTML with an `<img>` tag.

Comment: Yes this is how it is right now and it's working with `<img>`, but I wanted to add text to some parts of the card and I thought that positionting the text would be easier when it's set as a background, but I will have to figure a way to do it with `<img>`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this `height: max-content;`

Comment: It is still 0 height from some reason in my case

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.column_flex_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex_image {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("my_img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
```

if the aspect ratio of the image is 16:9, set the padding-bottom of the flex item to 56.25% (9 divided by 16 times 100)

Comment: You no longer need to use padding to make aspect ratios work. Now you can simply say `aspect-ratio: 16/9;`